# Typescript Support in Notepad++

Tags: typescript, notepad++

It seems like Notepad++ App is missing Typescript from its list of supported languages.

Is that correct or am I missing something?

Notepad++ Version: 7.8.2

[Notepad++ Language Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLWUd.png)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/chai2010/notepadplus-typescript) helps you.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Editor-Support#notepad

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As answered by [@Monsignor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72978221/2436655), TypeScript is supported since [v8.1.4](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/v814-released/). Though it is not listed at the [manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/programing-languages/).

Notepad++ does not support TypeScript ([Supported Programming Languages](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/programing-languages/)).

However, you might want to try [Notepad++ support for TypeScript](https://github.com/chai2010/notepadplus-typescript)¹, which is also referred by [Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Editor-Support) on its list for TypeScript editor support.

¹ Unfortunately the last commit was in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is on the list since version 8.1.4

See https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/v814-released/

Comment: Needs uninstall and install of Notepad++  8.1.4 or greater version. You can try side-by-side portable version

Answer (score 1):

Typescript support was added in 8.1.4 release but you will have to uninstall notepad++ and install it again (I don't know why).

[Typescript support in Notepadd++ 8.1.4](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/v814-released/)